# How do I deploy multiple PHP scripts on Google Cloud?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am deploying a php code on google cloud- which should include 3 php scripts, but only the index.php is displayed when deployed.

```
runtime: php73
# serve script entries like this
- url: /index.php
  script: auto

- url: /check.php
  script: auto

- url: /reset.php
  script: auto
```

I have tried to change the url and script in app.yaml file, but since it's php73 version there's an error that the script must be set on auto for that version.

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP 7 standard environment of App Engine you should use a front controller to control your application routing as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#application_startup)